# Upload certificate to Azure Function App via IAC

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform, azure-function-app

Thus far we've been manually uploading certificates to Azure Function Apps (using the Azure portal), I'm just wondering if anyone's found a simple way of automating this?

Looking at the terraform docs, I can't see any way of adding certificates through infrastructure as code: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app.html

Has anyone come up with a good automated solution?